# Changing Icon per Day

Tags: ios, calendar, icons

Just like the Calendar app on the iphones and ipods, how do I make the Icon change per day?

Comment: Since `iOS 10.3` this is possible! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950994/is-this-possible-to-apply-the-alternative-icon-to-the-ios-application

Answer (score 9):

I assume this is for an iOS app. The answers is, you can't. The Calendar app has access to functionality in iOS that us mere mortal developers cannot access. You may be able to pull this off with a jailbroken phone, but I've never tried that.

Comment: I do have a jailbroken iphone. but how would i go about doing so?

Answer (score 5):

Since changing the icon is not officially supported, if it's numerical information you want to show, you can use the Notification Badge instead.

[Updating iOS badge without push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861131/updating-ios-badge-without-push-notifications)

So you could make it show today's date in the badge, and schedule the badge to update at midnight, or show the current temperature and schedule it to update hourly.

Comment: Can you provide a link to changing the icon is officially supported?

Answer (score 3):

There is a new solution for this situation.
You can use
setAlternateIconName(_:completionHandler:)
iOS 10.3 is out with xcode 8.3.

[check out solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41849979/948445)