# Changing the app icon with MonoTouch every day

Tags: calendar, xamarin.ios, icons

How do I change the icon of the app after it is installed?
I need it to kind of reflect the date, just like the calendar app.

Comment: I don't believe there is any public API that allows you to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Icon per Day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038305/changing-icon-per-day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the app icon programmatically is not allowed i am afraid. It must match the icon supplied to the App Store.

Comment: So doing something like the buildin calendar is not possible at all?

Comment: No i am afraid not, that is using private API's which are not available to us mere mortals developers. :)

Comment: You can use the badge, if that helps you. (Show a little red circle with a number in it)