# different app icon for different country

Tags: app-store-connect, ios9

I have released a German app for iPhone (swift 2 ios 9). Now I would like to add the English language. The problem is, that my app icon will not be understood in countries with English language. It should still be the same app, but use another icon for the app in English speaking countries.

Is this possible to set 2 different app icons für different localizations?

Comment: based on coordenates? gps?

Comment: based on iphone language. 
if language == englisch = app icon 1 ; if not = app icon 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669858/change-app-icon-programatically