# Is there any way to change the app icon dynamically in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to change the app icon dynamically. I receive the image from the server. How do I use that image as alternative app icon. Please make sure the answer is clear. (but as I know, the alternative app icon file should be in our project plist file).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097604/alternate-icon-in-ios-10-3

Comment: thanks for reply but i want it dynamically.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot change your app icon with an image downloaded from a server at runtime. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname):

> You must declare your app's primary and alternate icons using the `CFBundleIcons` key of your app's `Info.plist` file. For information about how to configure alternate icons for your app, see the description of the `CFBundleIcons` key in [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009247).

In order to dynamically set an app icon, you must be able to define it in your `Info.plist`, but your `Info.plist` is included in your app bundle, and your app bundle is read-only, so you do not have runtime write access to your `Info.plist` file. Thus, you cannot change your app icon to an image dynamically downloaded at runtime

Comment: can you set the info plist to an image that will then be downloaded at runtime?

Comment: I don't think so. I believe they need to be compiled into your app's bundle so iOS knows where to find them. There isn't a way to set it to a specific file, only a name that you list in your `Info.plist`, and I don't think iOS checks your app's runtime-writable directories

Answer (score 1):

Apple launches a cool function so that developers are able to programmatically change the app icon.

In Apple's API document, there are 3 things worth a glance:

```
var supportsAlternateIcons: Bool { get }
var alternateIconName: String? { get }
func setAlternateIconName(String?, completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

Info.plist
[image]

Now we just call the method:

```
changeIcon(to: "icon-imageName")
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806815-supportsalternateicons