# how to include the icons in the app using a font file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i am very new to font file. i wanted to used font file to display images/icons for my iPhone App.

i read over net about custom font but i wanted .ttf file for display of images.icons.

is it possible to display even App icon using font file, at present i am using Assets.xcassets =>  AppIcon i have all my PNG formate icon saved here.

Please, any one show me how to use .ttf file to include the icons/Images in the app. or to Display App Icon.
do i have to create .ttf file with icon/images?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

Comment: no i don not want custom font but ICON which i am using in APP, need to include by .ttf file , creating ICON FONT File.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot set app icon from a custom font, refer for instance to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042275/can-i-change-app-icon-programmatically