# Dynamic icon iOS

Tags: ios, springboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing Icon per Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038305/changing-icon-per-day)

How to make a dynamic icon? For example in the calendar. Each day the number is changes to the current. Is it possible to implement this in my application?

Comment: From iOS 10.3 it's possible:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname?language=objc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't currently possible without a jailbreak

Comment: not exactly the jailbreak is needed to do it, just there is no official `API` to do this feature, and if you use any un-official third part `API`, your application cannot be published in the Appstore, it will be rejected.

Comment: actually a jailbreak is required to do this, for the very reason that an Apple-sanctioned API is not available

Comment: What bugs me is that they made the clock fully dynamic, and the calendar, but didn't make this available to the public.