# Can we make Animated icons for iOS 7 now in Xcode?

Tags: dynamic, icons, ios7

When i saw new iOS 7.0 then i saw clock icon is on running state. So i am curious to know, that can we also make icons dynamically by Xcode?

i googled also about this but didn't found any question or hint on this.

Comment: Simply you can't do this.

Answer (score 2):

No, we're not able to created animated Springboard icons. The following still applies to iOS7.

[Changing Icon per Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038305/changing-icon-per-day)

[Dynamic icon iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884260/dynamic-icon-ios)