# iOS7 Change App Icon on the fly

Tags: ios7

Can we change the app icon (icon which you see on the home screen) on the fly or based on the setting. 
Usually this icon is pre set before publishing the app on app store. As user installs the app it comes on the home screen. 
We can change the icon later any point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097807/dynamically-change-iphone-app-icon-and-loading-image and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884260/dynamic-icon-ios

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the app icon can be changed on the fly. The configuration for the icon is static and part of the build settings.

Answer (score 0):

No. Jailbreaking your phone seems to be the only option. Also, this has been asked many times before:

- [Can we make Animated icons for iOS 7 now in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088977/can-we-make-animated-icons-for-ios-7-now-in-xcode)
- [Dynamic icon iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884260/dynamic-icon-ios)
- [Changing Icon per Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038305/changing-icon-per-day)