# How to create dynamic icon like calendar icon of ios 7?

Tags: ios7

I want to create dynamic text changing icon like the calendar app in iOS 7 is there any way to do so?

Comment: Nope. Definitely not without jailbreaking

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Icon per Day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038305/changing-icon-per-day)

Comment: yes their is way of doing that...you just need to write a script.

Comment: We can change the app icon dynamically, not flexible as built in Clock and calendar icon. By using these API's we can change app icons https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806815-supportsalternateicons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not do this, there is no API allowing this.

Your apps icon is in your application bundle which is readonly and therefor can not be modified.

Comment: yes i know this read only thing but how iOS 7 calendar icon manages there must be some way out

Comment: Well no, the clock is also changing, but you have no access these APIS. Just because Apple apps can do it, does not mean you can. Unless you are running your app on a jailbroke device you are out of luck.

Comment: Apple has good reasons to disallow it. It would make fora lousy user experience as all apps would fight for attention by animating more and more, creating a cacophony. And it would destroy battery life. Ultimately app developers are being saved from themselves.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry brother ... !! There is no API for your requirement. Apple does this only for their apps. Your app icon must be bundled with your application bundle.