# How can i make app icon responsive like iOS built in clock and calendar icon

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to make a realtime icon like Clock and Calendar icon in iOS.
I don't know how its made so can anyone please give some suggestion.

Is it possible or not, and if possible then guide me how can i implement it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic icon like calendar icon of ios 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866911/how-to-create-dynamic-icon-like-calendar-icon-of-ios-7)

Comment: Nope, it's not possible and there are other questions here about this problem.

Comment: ohh ok sorry for that.

Comment: We can change the app icon dynamically, not flexible as built in Clock and calendar icon. By using these API's we can change app icons https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806815-supportsalternateicons

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not provide any API for such. It would be better if they allow to use developers this kind of features. So the answer is no, you can not animate your app icon. Please do some RnD on SO, it's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361654/how-to-animate-application-icon-in-ios)