# How can an app’s icon change dynamically in iOS 10.3, like iOS's clock app?

Tags: ios, icons, ios10.3

Apple's Clock app changes its icon dynamically. Is this possible now for third-party apps in iOS 10.3 and later?

Comment: you should take a look at this post :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950994/is-this-possible-to-apply-the-alternative-icon-to-the-ios-application