# iOS 10.3 - How to change app icon programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios10.3, appicon

iOS 10.3 comes with dynamic app icon changing feature. Developers will now be able to change app icons without an app update.

I want to change my app icon dynamically, how can i change my app icon programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname ?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950994/is-this-possible-to-apply-the-alternative-icon-to-the-ios-application

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-change-your-app-icon-dynamically-with-setalternateiconname

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, iOS 10.3 finally gives developers the ability to change their app’s icon programmatically.

It is possible to change appIcon from iOS 10.3. For that you need to set `supportsAlternateIcon` to `Yes` in `info.plist`.

Both primary and secondary icons should be added in `CFBundleIcons` key of your app's `Info.plist` file.

```
//Info.plist
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleAlternateIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Icon1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>alternater1</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>Icon2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>alternater2</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

To change App Icon following UIApplication method needs to be called:

**Objective C:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setAlternateIconName:@"alternater2" completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"Error...");
}];
```

**Swift 3:**

```
if UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons{
        UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("alternater2", completionHandler: { (error) in
            print(error ?? "")
        })
}
```

For more detailed tutorial, See:

[Apple Document: setAlternateIconName(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname)

[How to change your app icon dynamically with setAlternateIconName()](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-change-your-app-icon-dynamically-with-setalternateiconname)