# How feasible it is to change App icon of a Xamarin application based on certain notification statuses that it receives

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I would like to know if there is any way that helps to change application launcher icon based on the notification status it receives using xamarin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, at least not in iOS, the App Icon is defined in the Info.plist which is not writeable by the app, it's call bundled together by the developer - see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW10

There's no official way of doing out in Android, and whilst there are a few hacks (not Xamarin specific), your mileage may vary per device - see [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Not true, you can change iOS icon programatically now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233675/ios-10-3-how-to-change-app-icon-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change the "app icons" dynamically on both platforms now, but on iOS you can only change "app name" based on language preference!

### iOS

Here's how to [change app icon on iOS using Xamarin](https://prototypemakers.medium.com/userscustomizeiosappiconsxamarin-9d08b671e4e8?sk=3648f81068f011f81054c54926e9dbc7):

```
if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.SupportsAlternateIcons){
    await UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetAlternateIconNameAsync(iconName);
}
```

### Android

Android app icon can be changed by adding an alias identical to your activity in the AndroidManifest and then just switching which one the app uses [as shown here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-app-icon-of-android-programmatically-in-android/):

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>  
</activity>
<activity-alias 
  android:name=".MainActivityAlias" 
  android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_p_foreground"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:enabled="false" 
  android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">  
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>  
</activity-alias>
```

and then run this code whenever you want to change the icon:

```
PackageManager.SetComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName(this, "{bundleId}.MainActivityAlias"),
                ComponentEnabledState.Enabled,
                ComponentEnableOption.DontKillApp);
PackageManager.SetComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName(this, "{bundleId}.MainActivity"),
                ComponentEnabledState.Disabled,
                ComponentEnableOption.DontKillApp);
```

You can use the same concept of Dependency Injection shown in the iOS article I shared above in order to change the android icon from your Xamarin forms code