# Can Logo and Name of the App Change After Login? Swift

Tags: swift, authentication

Let's say that the logo of the app is simple W and the name of the app is My Life.

After login with a business mail I want to change the name of the app and the logo according to the business mail.

Is it possible and if yes how?

Comment: You can't change the name of the app. You can change the icon (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname) but it has to be confirmed by the user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43233675/1187415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change an app icon if the app already contains the desired icon (see https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-change-your-app-icon-dynamically-with-setalternateiconname); you cannot, say, download an icon and switch to it from within the app.

You cannot change an app display name at all. It is set through the info.plist. It can be localized (so that it changes if the user changes languages) but not altered.