# Change app icon to generated one in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios10.3

In iOS 10.3 Apple added [API for alternating icon](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname). I need to change app icon to icon generated in a runtime. Is there a way to generate `CFBundleIcon` in a runtime so I could make icon change?

Comment: check this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950994/is-this-possible-to-apply-the-alternative-icon-to-the-ios-application". Nice description.

Comment: No, you can only select from one of the icons that are included with your original bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in info plist:-

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleAlternateIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>ALTERNATE_APP_ICON_NAME</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>ALTERNATE_APP_ICON_NAME</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>AppIcon60x60</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

---

Once you made changes in info plist. You need to add following code:

Objective c:-

```
[[UIApplicationsharedApplication] setAlternateIconName:@"ALTERNATE_APP_ICON_NAME"completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"Error...");
    }];
```

Swift:

```
if UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons{
    UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("alternater2", completionHandler: { (error) in
        print(error ?? "")
    })
```

}

Comment: This doesn't solve OP's problem. They are specifically asking about setting an icon created dynamically (not in the app's bundle). This code cannot do that, and there's no way to change the app icon to an un-bundled one.