# Dynamically create app icon

Tags: ios

Now that you can change app icons in iOS I am wondering if they need to be images already included in the bundle or if I can dynamically create an image file in code and assign it as the app icon?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41951099/1187415, you can't.

Comment: Apple stopped allowing this a loooong time ago.

Comment: On a side note: if you want to create this sort of behaviour for your app, you might want to develop an app widget.

Answer (score 1):

The image must already be included in the bundle.

You can use `UIApplication.setAlternateIconName` to change the icon easily, but you would want to read up on the [common pitfalls](https://samwize.com/2017/08/20/how-to-change-ios-app-icon-programmatically-ios-10-3/).